# Clairs fanaux, vivantes opales -- where is the 8th syllable?

Tags: grammaire

I'm reading poem *Le chat* by Charles Baudelaire, I'm a bit confused at the line

> Clairs fanaux, vivantes opales

as it sounds only have 7 syllables? -- I interpret it as

> Clairs  · fa · naux,  · vi · vantes  · o · pales

Here *vantes* I only count it as 1 as the next word started with *o*, and *pales* also count as 1 as it's the ending of the line.

Where did I miss it? Is it that *vantes* shall count as 2 as its *s* will link with the next *o*?

The full content of the poem is below

> Le chat
>
> Charles Baudelaire
>
> De sa fourrure blonde et brune
> Sort un parfum si doux, qu'un soir
> J'en fus embaumé, pour l'avoir
> Caressée une fois, rien qu'une.
>
> C'est l'esprit familier du lieu;
> Il juge, il préside, il inspire
> Toutes choses dans son empire;
> Peut-être est-il fée, est-il dieu?
>
> Quand mes yeux, vers ce chat que j'aime
> Tirés comme par un aimant,
> Se retournent docilement,
> Et que je regarde en moi-même,
>
> Je vois avec étonnement
> Le feu de ses prunelles pâles,
> Clairs fanaux, vivantes opales,
> Qui me regardent fixement.

Comment: Clairs fa-naux, vi-van-te- zo-pales, 8 syllables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it that *vantes* shall count as 2 as its s will link with the next o?

Precisely:  /vi.vɑ̃.tø.zo.pal/